# django-compressor: disable caching using precompilers

Tags: django, django-compressor

I'm using [django-compressor](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to compile scss files.
Every time I modify the scss file, django-compressor build a css file in `/static/CACHE/css/123456.css`.

It's ok for pruduction mode, but when I'm developing on local I have a revision for every change I do.

So, in development mode, how can I force the output to a file with the same name ?

Its not a problem of revison control...

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-sass', 'sass --compass "{infile}" "{outfile}"'),
    ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss --compass "{infile}" "{outfile}"'),
)
```

Comment: it does not answer your question but wouldn't it be more logic to add /static/* or /static/CACHE/* to .gitignore (if you are using git)?

Comment: Sure, I do that. I want only to disable writing a lot of files during dev on my pc.

Comment: Can I see your code being called to compile the SCSS files please?

Comment: So is your problem the quantity of files written, or the time that it takes to do so (causing slow page loads when you're developing)?

Comment: The first one: "the quantity of files written", thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename for the cached file is actually based on it's contents. From the Django Compressor docs:

> **Generating the combined file if needed**
>
> The file is generated if necessary. All precompilers are called and
>   all filters are executed, and a hash is determined from the contents.
>   This in turns helps determine the file name, which is only saved if it
>   didn’t exist already. Then the HTML output is returned (and also saved
>   in the cache). And that’s it!

http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/behind-the-scenes/#third-step-generating-the-combined-file-if-needed

I don't think there's any way you can make Django Compressor use a specified name without changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your SCSS files still have to go through a [matching precompiler](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_ENABLED) before you get a working output for your static assets.

In a properly configured development environment, you'd respect that the static output directory is not located/distributed with your application sources and the resulting CSS files would be tucked away from your sources somewhere on a path that's not under revision control.

EDIT:

Right, so I've missed the correct issue. The only solution is to disable compressor in development, including clearing out the precompiler MIME mappings, and resort to conditionally including client-side compilers in your master template.

This would make it possible to reference the original, unauthored [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) sources in development, but sadly I can't find a client-side SASS compiler.

Comment: ok, but my problem is not exclude the output dir from revision control, but not write a lot of files during dev.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved, but it involves a little bit of customisation. I have this exact setup working. I use local dev mode on dev, and in production (heroku) offline compression.

See the bottom of this issue for the code.
https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/226

Comment: It is preferable to inline a code snipet, as well as posting a link to the source. That way if the source goes offline or moves, we will still have a valid answer here. Thanks!